# Navigate to child component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

How to navigate correctly to a child component in angular 4?

Here i have the route object:

```
{
    path: ':name',
    component: parentComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'string_title'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'child/:id',
            component: childComponent,
            resolve: {
                data: DataResolver
            },
            data: {
                title: null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

trying to navigate to child component by this way:

```
this.router.navigate(['child', item], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

After navigating url should be something like this:
**parent/child/3**

At the moment it redirects me to home page when i'm trying to navigate to child component. What's wrong in this logic?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your code from where you are trying to access this route

Comment: @ShashankGaurav this `this.router.navigate(['child', item], {relativeTo: this.route});`

Comment: I mean which component? what is your current route which your child route is relative to?

Comment: @ShashankGaurav i resolved the problem with navigation, it works now, but it's another question here, after navigation on child page also parent template it's visible, but it shouldn't

Comment: May I ask you what was the solution?